# Python - mutate row elements using array of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

given the following array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10, 11, 12]])
```

I can create an array of indices:

```
b = np.array([0, 2, 0, 1])
```

and mutate one element from each row using the indices:

```
a[np.arange(4),b] += 10
```

which yields:

```
[[11  2  3]
 [ 4  5 16]
 [17  8  9]
 [10 21 12]]
```

Is there a more readable way to achieve the same result instead of `a[np.arange(4),b] += 10`?

Comment: Looks like a decent approach to me. What do you find un-readable?

Comment: a bit cryptic, for a noob like me. I was wondering if I could have a work around `arange()`.

Comment: Hide the implementation inside a func with a nice name for a *readable* code, if I got the interpretation of *readable* correctly there :) Spend few mins at `NumPy indexing` docs, it's a lot fun, trust me!

Comment: You can make it more readable with comments :-)

Comment: For small size arrays `a[range(b.size), b]` might be sightly more readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe writing it out more explicitly would help for "readability":

```
x = np.array([0, 2, 0, 1])
y = numpy.arange(x.size)
a[y, x] += 10
```

Otherwise, you are doing it in a very clear and succinct way, in my opinion.

Another option is to use a `ufunc`:

```
numpy.add.at(a, [y,x], 10)
```

Or if you prefer not to use `numpy.arange`:

```
y = numpy.indices((x.size,))
```